# python, trying to read a file but it doesn't find it

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a csv file on python but it doesn't recognice it, I've tried with this:

```
import pandas as pd
galicia = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/marta/OneDrive/Documentos/edades_gal')
```

but it returns:

```
[Errno 2] File C:/Users/marta/OneDrive/Documentos/edades_gal does not exist: 'C:/Users/marta/OneDrive/Documentos/edades_gal'
```

Comment: You're missing the `.csv` extension.

Comment: extension `extension` extension !!! follow this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas-read-csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file exits at that location then you can use r before the file path it will work and also as mentioned in comments use file extension in the file path.

```
import pandas as pd 
galicia = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/marta/OneDrive/Documentos/edades_gal.csv')
```

Comment: Raw strings have nothing to do with this, there aren't any backslashes (\\) in the string.